# Excel trim text based on variable input

Tags: excel, replace, trim, substitution

I have a string I would like to trim after once occurrence of "." after it sees ".IS"  The characters before (and after) the ".IS" are variable until the next occurrence of a "."  The only thing that is standard is the ".IS" and that there will be more characters following.

I need this to be in a formula so as new data is added it is automatically trimmed.

For Example:

```
11.34367.3729.IS3432.12 -> 11.34367.3729.IS3432
12.7232.372.123.IS280.1.5 -> 12.7232.372.123.IS280
836.823.135.IS289673.1.45 -> 836.823.135.IS289673
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),1,FIND("IS",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99)))+99))," ",".")
```

[image]